# Add multiples 'background' into a css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to add all the webkits in a `background` of a unique css class. I have multiples div with the same class, someone told me that I could use a query function like:

```js
var cor1 = "000";
var cor2 = "fff";

function pegar_as_duas_cores_e_gerar_gradient_para_o_galao() {

  var gradient1 = "-moz-linear-gradient(top, #" + cor1 + " 0%, #" + cor2 + " 100%) !important;";
  var gradient2 = "-webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #" + cor1 + "), color-stop(100%, #" + cor2 + " )) !important;";
  var gradient3 = "-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #" + cor1 + " 0%, #" + cor2 + " 100%) !important;";
  var gradient4 = "-o-linear-gradient(top, #" + cor1 + " 0%, #" + cor2 + " 100%) !important;";
  var gradient5 = "-ms-linear-gradient(top, #" + cor1 + " 0%, #" + cor2 + " 100%) !important;";
  var gradient6 = "linear-gradient(to bottom, #" + cor1 + " 0%, #" + cor2 + " 100%) !important;";

  $('.conteudoGalao').css({
    'background': gradient1,
    'background': gradient2,
    'background': gradient3,
    'background': gradient4,
    'background': gradient5,
    'background': gradient6
  });
}

$('#btn_teste').click(function() {
  pegar_as_duas_cores_e_gerar_gradient_para_o_galao();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desenhoGalao">
  <div class="tampaGalao"></div>
  <div class="conteudoGalao"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn_teste">Test</button>
```

The function `pegar_as_duas_cores_e_gerar_gradient_para_o_galao()` does not work, but why? Can I actually use `.css({...})` ? It's actually the first time I've seen a query like this.

**EDIT:**

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304626/setting-os-ms-prefix-for-background-gradient-in-jquery-fails-to-work) and changed the code to:

```
var cor1 = "000";
var cor2 = "fff";
function pegar_as_duas_cores_e_gerar_gradient_para_o_galao(){
    var i, l, backgrounds = [
                    '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #' + cor1 + ' 0%, #'  + cor2 + ' 100%)',
                    '-webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #' + cor1 + '), color-stop(100%, #'  + cor2 + ' ))',
                    '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #' + cor1 + ' 0%, #'  + cor2 + ' 100%)',
                    '-o-linear-gradient(top, #' + cor1 + ' 0%, #'  + cor2 + ' 100%)',
                    '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #' + cor1 + ' 0%, #'  + cor2 + ' 100%)',
                    'linear-gradient(to bottom, #' + cor1 + ' 0%, #'  + cor2 + ' 100%)'
                ];
                for( i = 0, l = backgrounds.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
                    $('conteudoGalao').css({ background: backgrounds[i] });
                }
                $('.conteudoGalao').css({
                    'filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#" + cor1 + "', endColorstr='#" + cor2 + "', GradientType=0 )"
                });
            }

            $('#btn_teste').click(function(){
                pegar_as_duas_cores_e_gerar_gradient_para_o_galao();
            });
```

It doesn't work either. Both of them doesn't even show me an error or anything. Any ideas?

Comment: You are basically using this https://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/

Comment: Why simply not doing that with pure css ? or sass with prefixer ?

Comment: @J.Wallner because with Jquery you can change the value for the variable colors any time you want ? and also with the action of a button ...

Comment: @DaniP thanks for your help bro, I will try that `for()` later.

Comment: @DaniP It didn't work :( Doesn't show me any error or anything, just like the `.css({...})`

Comment: Remove the !important from your variables

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you always overwrite your background with another value..

You should not do something like: element{background: xxx, background: xxx} but instead do this: element{background: xxx, xxx, xxx}

Full explanation: [MDN Multiple Backgrounds CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)